# Git log formatting just one author

Tags: git, git-log

I'm trying to log all of my commits, organized by day for log tracking. I want it to look like this:

Commit message      Author      Date

So the actual log would look something like:

`Fixed spacing on homepage      Terry      July 27, 2015`

The closest I've found so far is this: 
`git log --author="Terry" --date=iso --pretty=format:'%ad%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%aN %s'`

But I'm not actually able to interpret any of the 08% business to be able to change it to be exactly what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

`git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --author="Steve"`

even better, if you just need date without timestamp:

`git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --author="Steve" --date=short`

If you want all the authors then remove the `--author` option in above command.

More info: http://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Comment: For bonus — any idea how I can pipe this out to Sublime text?

Comment: append this ` > mygitlog.log` & open with SublimeText :)

Comment: Sublime Text comes with a command line tool, subl.  You can pipe your git command directly into that and it will open in a tab in Sublime.  E.g., `git log --oneline | subl`.   Hmmm, which works for me on Linux and Mac OS X but not on Windows.  Sorry.

Comment: @Wolf, In your case someone might have configured it for you, it wont come by default you need to configure it manually(to open sublime using commandline) see my gist for ST3 https://gist.github.com/udaykadaboina#launch-sublime-text-3-from-the-mac-os-x-terminal

Answer (score 1):

you can find the info on all those options to pretty=format [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

the ones that interest you:

- %ad: author date (format respects --date= option)
- %x08. From the documentation: `%x00: print a byte from a hex code`, and byte 08 means "backspace", so this basically means to remove a character from the output
- %aN: author name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) or git-blame[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))

so in fact the bloc `%ad%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08` basically means: print the date, and then do some backspaces to keep only the date (and not the time,...)

Comment: Awesome! And finally figured out what the x08 thing does. Weird though.

Comment: Here's what worked for me in the end:   `git log --pretty=format:"%ad %Cblue %ar %Creset %aN -  %C(blue) %s %creset %x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08" --author="Terry" --date=short
`